# Distributed C/C++ Engine with Python

Tags: python, tesseract, py2exe, pyinstaller

I am using an C based OCR engine known as `tesseract` with Python interface library `pytesseract` to access its core features. Essentially, the library reads the local contents of the installed engine for use in a Python program. However, the library continues to look for the engine when distributed as an executable. How do I instead include the engine self-contained in the executable?

Comment: How is this unclear? You people are so quick to jump on the downvote bandwagon.

Comment: There is an external OCR program installed which I need to include in the executable.

Comment: did I get you right that pytesseract is included in the exefied script but the exefied script still requires tesseract?

Comment: You can try using this another library to use Tesseract in Python: [pyslibtesseract](https://github.com/brunomacabeusbr/pyslibtesseract).

Comment: Can someone who understands this question please fix the title?

Answer (score 2):

Reading the pytesseract docs, I have found the following section:

> Install google tesseract-ocr from
>   `http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/`. You must be able to invoke
>   the tesseract command as "tesseract". If this isn't the case, for
>   example because tesseract isn't in your PATH, you will have to change
>   the "tesseract_cmd" variable at the top of 'tesseract.py'.

This means you need to have tersseract installed on your target machine independent of your script being exefied or not. Tesseract is a requirement for your script to work. You will need to ask your users to have tesseract installed or you use an "install wizzard" tool which will check if tesseract is installed and if not install it for your users. But this is not the task of pyinstaller. Pyinstaller only exefies your Python script.

Comment: Is there a way to copy the installation folder into the script?

Comment: Sorry I do not know how to install tesseract. I have just given you a hint so you understand how pyinstaller works and how it can be used. You can add binary files to your exefied script. If tesseract does not need installation but only the files need to be extracted, you could add the files to your exefied script.

Comment: Okay, I think I have an idea.